# Built two different Debian packages for different Build Types using CMake

Tags: cmake, debian, debian-stretch

I have a small CMake project with different Build Types `debug` and `release`. I'm also providing a Debian package for this project. Building the Debian Package for `release` and providing it on my own Debian repository works perfect.

Now I also want to provide another Debian package for `debug`, due to debugging purposes, with a different package name. For example, my project is called `myproject`, and the debugging package should be `myproject-debug`.

I already read documentation about how to solve this in the `debian/control` file. I want to use `Replaces: ...` on each package vice versa, so that you can install only one of the both packages at a time. So either `myproject` or `myproject-debug`, but not both at the same time, to use the exact same files and filenames but only the binary has more debugging informations and debug prints in the `myproject-debug` package. Everything else should be the same. Same filename, same paths, etc.

Now the problem is that I don't know how the `debian/rules` file should look like, to first build the `myproject` package in a folder and then build the `myproject-debug` with different CMake options (`-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug`) in a different folder, so the filenames can and should stay the same.

There is this [CMake tutorial](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch08.en.html#cmake-multi) in the Debian documentation, but this doesn't fit my requirements. Because in this tutorial everything will be built in only one folder, and in this one folder there are different files. Then different `.install` files will be used to copy the needed files to each package. But since I have the same binary filename for each package `myproject` and `myproject-debug` this tutorial does not really fit my needs.

I already have the following lines in my `debian/rules` file:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release
```

But how can I run two different builds with two different build types?

For example, something like this, to split it up:

```
override_dh_auto_configure_release:
    dh_auto_configure -- -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release

override_dh_auto_configure_debug:
    dh_auto_configure -- -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug
```

And run both in different folders so I can add both folders to two different packages.

Or maybe there is even a better solution I cannot imagine yet?

Comment: Perhaps the following answer is helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/317731/examples-of-multiple-binary-packages